# How to lock the camera app orientation called through intent in android?

Tags: android, camera, orientation

I want to open the native camera app through intent in my application. I have used the following lines of code.

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actionCode);
```

Now, I want to **lock the orientation of camera in portrait when it is opened**. I just added the below line to the above piece of code.

```
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION,
                    ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

But, it is not working. The Camera opened is not locked to portrait. It is moving in all the orientation. Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: did u get a solution to this??

Answer (score -2):

To force portrait orientation:

place  `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I have tried it. This locks the activity which starts the camera intent. But not the camera's orientation