# How to lock CAMERA intent app orientation

Tags: android

I'm creating an application that is intended to run only in portrait mode.
In the application I'm invoking the Android native camera app using an intent.
When the phone is in portrait orientation the application works as expected.
When the phone is in landscape orientation the camera application is launched in landscape orientation, this causes the main activity and my fragment to be recreated when the camera intent is closed which causes some unintentional behavior.

Is there any way to force the camera application to open only in portrait orientation when launching it via intent?

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to lock the orientation to Portrait when using intent ACTION\_IMAGE\_CAPTURE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427596/how-to-lock-the-orientation-to-portrait-when-using-intent-action-image-capture)

Answer (score 0):

Just add **android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"**
in your activity in Manifest.

Comment: Correct, this will keep the orientation of the app activity as per last state but will not change the orientation in the camera app.

Answer (score -1):

Use this in the onCreate() menthod of your camera activity.

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);